# How to check if a Meteor package is currently installed?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to check if the package `my-package:notification` is installed in my app.

Only then another template is used (which is part of this package).

Something like this:

```
<template name="example">
    {{#if hasNotificationPackage}}
        {{>notification}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor provides a global object called `Package` that contains all of the Meteor package exports.

Therefore, you can use something like

```
Template.example.helpers({
  hasNotificationPackage() {
    return (typeof Package['my-package:notification'] === 'object');
  }
});
```

I am not sure that depending on the availability of a package this way is something that should be used often, especially in production.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your package uses an object/variable that is accessible in your projects. You just need to write a helper for the workaround

```
Template.example.helpers({
hasNotificationPackage: function(){
         return (PackageObj) ? true: false; //PackageObj is your package permissible object
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you give me an example how you would create the `PackageObj`?

Comment: I/you would not be creating the object. It's package author who make this object accessible. here `PackageObj` is just an illustration